# Exact XPATH location within Java

Tags: xpath, rapidminer

I'm trying to return exact XPATH query expressions so I can datamine a site with rapidminer.
I need a query to isolate each line individually:

> Wed 7/11/2012
>
> TROLL
>
> 9999999999999
>
> 07.11.12
>
> CONNOTE FILE LODGED
>
> Tue 20/11/2012 1:12 PM

So far all I have is `//td[@class='select']/text()`

Note: The values will change so the query needs to be location specific.

What would the six separate queries be for each of the values?

```
        <tr>
          <td class="select" onClick="javascript:window.location.href = 'consignmentDetails.do;jsessionid=7e6a45cbddf07ecba7741e5020b4bfe76e53b8f5df9ea83eaf2040b991792d25.e3iMc3eQax8Re34Qb3aKbNmOch90?consignment=1388730000024&recordCreatedBy=FIMS&groupId=';" onMouseOver="backColorChange(this,'FFFFCC')" onMouseOut="backColorChange(this,'ffffff')">
            Wed 7/11/2012<br>
            TROLL&nbsp;
            
          </td>
          <td class="select" align="center" onClick="javascript:window.location.href = 'consignmentDetails.do;jsessionid=7e6a45cbddf07ecba7741e5020b4bfe76e53b8f5df9ea83eaf2040b991792d25.e3iMc3eQax8Re34Qb3aKbNmOch90?consignment=1388730000024&recordCreatedBy=FIMS&groupId=';" onMouseOver="backColorChange(this,'FFFFCC')" onMouseOut="backColorChange(this,'ffffff')">
            9999999999999
            <br>07.11.12
            
            &nbsp;
          </td>
          <td class="select" onClick="javascript:window.location.href = 'consignmentDetails.do;jsessionid=7e6a45cbddf07ecba7741e5020b4bfe76e53b8f5df9ea83eaf2040b991792d25.e3iMc3eQax8Re34Qb3aKbNmOch90?consignment=1388730000024&recordCreatedBy=FIMS&groupId=';" onMouseOver="backColorChange(this,'FFFFCC')" onMouseOut="backColorChange(this,'ffffff')">
             
              
              
                      
                CONNOTE FILE LODGED <br>
                Tue 20/11/2012 1:12 PM
              &nbsp;
            
            
            
&nbsp;
          </td>
          
        </tr>
      
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the Ruby library [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) (which stands on top of libxml2, implementing XPath 1.0) to test:

```rb
XPATHS = %w{
  //tr/td[1]/text()[1]
  //tr/td[1]/text()[2]
  //tr/td[2]/text()[1]
  //tr/td[2]/text()[2]
  //tr/td[3]/text()[1]
  //tr/td[3]/text()[2]
}

require 'nokogiri'
d = Nokogiri.HTML(html)

XPATHS.each{ |expression| p d.at_xpath(expression).content }
#=> "\n            Wed 7/11/2012"
#=> "\n            TROLL\u00A0\n\n          "
#=> "\n            9999999999999\n            "
#=> "07.11.12\n\n            \u00A0\n          "
#=> "\n\n\n\n\n                CONNOTE FILE LODGED "
#=> "\n                Tue 20/11/2012 1:12 PM\n              \u00A0\n\n\n\n\u00A0\n          "
```

As you can see, the text nodes contain a lot of extra leading and trailing whitespace that you probably want to strip out. We can strip this by using [`normalize-space`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space):

```rb
XPATHS = %w{
  normalize-space(//tr/td[1]/text()[1])
  normalize-space(//tr/td[1]/text()[2])
  normalize-space(//tr/td[2]/text()[1])
  normalize-space(//tr/td[2]/text()[2])
  normalize-space(//tr/td[3]/text()[1])
  normalize-space(//tr/td[3]/text()[2])
}

XPATHS.each{ |expression| p d.xpath(expression) }
#=> "Wed 7/11/2012"
#=> "TROLL\u00A0"
#=> "9999999999999"
#=> "07.11.12 \u00A0"
#=> "CONNOTE FILE LODGED"
#=> "Tue 20/11/2012 1:12 PM \u00A0 \u00A0"
```